# Finding the area of the region cut from the first quadrant by the curve

Tags: area, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

The problem requires me to find the area of the region cut from the first quadrant by the curve $r=2(2-\sin2\theta)^{1/2}$

Since it is in the first quadrant, I set $0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Also I set $0\le r\le 2(2-\sin2\theta)^{1/2}$.

Now I have that

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2(2-\sin2\theta)^{1/2}}rdrd\theta$$

It seems that I have to convert the double integral from polar to Cartesian, since I was in trouble with that power $\frac{1}{2}$.

$$
\begin{split}
r &= 2(2-\sin2\theta)^{1/2} \\
\implies r       &= 2(2-2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^{1/2} \\
\implies r^2     &= 8(1-\sin\theta\cos\theta) \\
\implies x^2+y^2 &= 8(1-\sin\theta\cos\theta)
\end{split}
$$
and then I stuck here.

Am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the graph of your curve below:

[image: PolarPlot]]

As you wrote, this sets up the integral as
$$
\begin{split}
I &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2(2-\sin(2\theta))^{1/2}}rdrd\theta \\
  &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \left[\frac{r^2}{2} \right]_0^{2(2-\sin(2\theta))^{1/2}}
                    d\theta \\
  &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2(2-\sin(2\theta)}{2} d\theta \\
  &= \int_0^{\pi/2} (2-\sin(2\theta) d\theta \\
\end{split}
$$

Can you now finish this?

Comment: Oops, thank you. I have overlooked the polar integral.